# Matching ProxyAddresses to Surname and Firstname

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm trying to pull some information from AD but having difficulty. I'm trying to get a list of users that have the PRIMARY smtp address from the ProxyAddresses attribute (an array) in a specific format (SMTP:firstname.lastname*) only. I only want the ones that match "SMTP" (case sensitive) and of those only those that have the email address in the format of firstname.lastname.

```
Get-ADUser -SearchBase "DC=corp,DC=companyx,DC=com" -Filter * -Properties ProxyAddresses,sn,givenname,displayname,mail |
    Where-Object {$_.ProxyAddresses -clike "SMTP:{$_.givenname+$_.sn}*"} # | Select-Object proxyaddresses,displayName,givenName,sn
```

Comment: The subexpression operator is `$()`. `"SMTP:{$_.givenname+$_.sn}*"` -> `"SMTP:$($_.givenname).$($_.sn)*"`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Get-ADUser -SearchBase "DC=corp,DC=companyx,DC=com" -Filter * -Properties ProxyAddresses,sn,givenname,displayname,mail | 
Where-object {($_.ProxyAddresses -cmatch "SMTP:") -and ($_.ProxyAddresses -match "$($_.givenname).$($_.sn)*")}
```

Comment: `($_.ProxyAddresses -match "$($_.givenname).$($_.sn)*")` will not work because the asteriks in regex is a quantifier character and does not do what it stands for with `like`.